# How to create AppDelegate to Third party Framework bridge file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, cocoapods, appdelegate

I have a project written in Objective C, new features are written in Swift 3.1
My requirement is accessing a variable declared in AppDelegate.h file. So I import AppDelegate in my bridge file. now I can declare Appdelegate Object in my Swift class file and also access variables declared in Appdelegate.

The problem is, after importing AppDelegate into the Bridge file, there is an error in the imported framework in AppDelegate.h file. "File not found"
If i remove AppDelegate.h from bridge file its works fine.

Appreciate your help

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DCPathButton.h"    <- ERROR IN THIS FRAMEWORK
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>



@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property NSInteger addUserFlag;
@property NSInteger addDeviceFlag;
@property NSInteger userProfileFlag;
@property NSInteger backToAddHomeFlag;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *loginResponseArray;
@property NSInteger AcFlag;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary *FCM_Dict;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *supportPhone;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *FCM_Key;
@property DCPathButton *dcPathButtonInAppDelgt;
@property  (strong,nonatomic) NSString *disableAddHomeBtn;
@property  (strong,nonatomic) NSString *disableAddRoomBtn;
@property  (strong,nonatomic) NSString *disableAddDeviceBtn;
@property  (strong,nonatomic) NSString *disableAddUserBtn;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *sideMenuFlag;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property NSInteger homeOrAwayFlag;
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `#import "DCPathButton.h"` to your AppDelegate.m and add this instead in the .h: `@class DCPathButton;`